# EZXML parser C and UTF-8 charset

Tags: c, utf-8, xml-parsing, non-ascii-characters

I am little confused with a possibilities of EZXML parser. It all worked well when I parsed characters from the ASCII range, but when I tried to parse non-ASCII characters (UTF-8), I got nothing.

Is EZXML made only for standard ASCII range, or it can for instance: show value of some non-standard char with hex value for example **D084**.

I don't know how to get that 2B value of char through EZXML parser.

When I do something like this

```
books = (ezxml_get(books_xml, "books", 0, "book", -1)->txt);
printf("%x \n", books[0]);
```

I only got 1B and D0 (MSB part of UTF-8 char hex value).

What to do?

Comment: EZXML comes with complete source code.  Q: Why don't you step through in the debugger to see what's going wrong?  Q: Does your XML [validate]*http://www.xmlvalidation.com/)?

Comment: I goes through source code, and I realized that pointer to char is 1B value, and cannot point to values greater than that. So thats maybe the reason why I only get MSB part of UTF-8 hex value. @paulsm4

Comment: There it is :)  SUGGESTION: Try a different library.  For example, I believe [Apache Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/) has full Unicode support.

Comment: [Mini-XML](http://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z3) if you're okay with LGPL v2 license, it has full support for UTF-8 and UTF-16, and a C interface. Otherwise libxml2 or libexpat.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/lxfontes/ezxml/blob/master/changelog.txt), UTF-8 & UTF-16 should be supported for EZXML 0.8.6 (which I presume you have).